# SharePoint 2010 KeywordQuery Managed Property Search

Tags: search, sharepoint-2010, keywordquery

In my test-system there is no problem searching for items within specific sites, using the **site:** tag. this looks like:

myTestSearch site:http://sharepoint.local/testsite/library1

The same webpart does have a problem with this keyword in the live-system on a different server. I don't get any results on that query.  Same Data, Same Configuration, Full Crawling done, Same Settings in Managed Properties...

What could work here against me?

Thanks for any hint or answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution that worked for me: instead of site: , I took path: , worked like a charm on both systems!